# SQL expression works in DB Manager but not in Query Builder/Filter, returns "OGR[3] error 1: Undefined function" error

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, translation, query-builder

I have a geopackage table/layer of buildings. I need to "offset" by using ST_Translate. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html

The expression `SELECT ST_Translate(geom, 1, 1, 0) FROM "building_UTM"` works when ran in the SQL Window of the DB Manager.

[image]

However, if the same expression is ran via the Query Builder/Filter function, it doesn't work and returns the following error

> An error occurred when executing the query.The data provider said:
> OGR[3] error 1: Undefined function 'ST_Translate' used.

[image]

I'm sure that this expression ran as expected in the Query Builder in my other laptop.

Comment: The Query Builder is not the same as the DB Manager. DB Manager allows you to query a PostgreSQL database, but the Query Builder uses the QGIS query engine. See https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#geometry-functions

Comment: Understood. I'll confirm in the QGIS in my other laptop if the SQL expression works in the QB.

Comment: I would just use the DB manager and create a layer from the query. But the QGIS Expression builder does have a translate function, as you can see if you search for translate in that document.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I still have to figure out how `translate()` works. I'm supposed to use the SQL expression in a PyQGIS script by putting it in the `QgsVectorLayer.setSubsetString()`. The other option is the `QgsVectorLayer.translateFeature()` method but it requires the layer to be in edit mode first.

Comment: Do you mean this is for an assignment that needs to be done in a certain way? I would highly recommend using GeoPandas to manipulate GeoPackages over PyQGIS, if you're doing this as a project

Comment: This is for a PyQGIS script so I'd like it to be 100% working out of the box with no needed external libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Query Builder is not the same as the DB Manager. DB Manager allows you to query using SQL syntax for various databases, but the Query Builder uses the QGIS expression engine. See https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html

I would just use the DB manager and create a layer from the query. But ff you want to do this within QGIS, check out the Field Calculator, where you can use the in-built `translate` function using the same syntax as the PostGIS function you're using in the first example:

```
 translate($geometry,1,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the screenshot you can see that the SQL builder is used to **filter** a given layer, so the expression you can write is only a `where` clause, which is automatically appended to `select * from givenLayer where` .

You can either load the layer from the DBManager (maybe include an ID field?) or do roughly the same using a virtual layer.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter your query, but make sure to include an ID and eventually other fields from your original layer...

Comment: Yes. I'm supposed to use the SQL expression in a PyQGIS script by putting it in the QgsVectorLayer.setSubsetString(). The other option is the QgsVectorLayer.translateFeature() method but it requires the layer to be in edit mode first. I'll include your answer as one of my options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the table in the geopackage was faulty, I guess. I had to re-save the shapefile to the geopackage to overwrite it. And when I ran the query in the Query Builder/Filter window, it worked.